# How to detect if any exe application is installed on client machine through browser

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cross-browser, browser

I am working on jsp/servlet web application. Can browser(jsp page) detect any (exe)application is installed or not on client machine? same as iTune.

**Requirement**: Detect from browser whether any (exe) application is installed on client machine or not.

Thanks

Comment: web application is not installed on client machine. This is why it is called web. It is installed on server. The only software client needs is a web browser. So, try to change your question, otherwise it does not sound reasonable.

Comment: On top of that: define "installed". I use putty for example but I never installed it; its just an executable I dumped somewhere.

Comment: I just want to detect any exe application is installed on client machine thought browser(jsp page).